# Why did Microsoft bring AppDomain back to .NET Core 3.0?

Tags: .net-core, appdomain

From memory, Microsoft took `AppDomain` away, and this mechanism has been shut down.

Now I suddenly find `AppDomain` has come back:

> Assembly System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\3.0.0\ref\netcoreapp3.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll

the assembly contains the AppDomain class.

Here is my question: why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Porting to .NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/porting-to-net-core/)

> **Why was it discontinued**? AppDomains require runtime support and are
>   generally quite expensive. While still implemented by CoreCLR, it’s
>   not available in .NET Native and we don’t plan on adding this
>   capability there.
>
> **What should I use instead?** AppDomains were used for different
>   purposes. For code isolation, we recommend processes and/or
>   containers. For dynamic loading of assemblies, we recommend the new
>   AssemblyLoadContext class.

**Furthermore**

> Of course, **just because something isn’t
>   available in .NET Core today doesn’t mean we discontinued it**. In most
>   cases, it simply means we haven’t had the time to investigate whether
>   porting would make sense or didn’t think it was relevant to the
>   application models .NET Core currently offers. Thus, this is an area
>   we’re highly interested in getting your feedback.

So what is actually supported?

[AppDomain Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?view=netframework-4.8)

> On .NET Core, the AppDomain implementation is limited by design and
>   does not provide isolation, unloading, or security boundaries. For
>   .NET Core, there is exactly one AppDomain. Isolation and unloading are
>   provided through AssemblyLoadContext. Security boundaries should be
>   provided by process boundaries and appropriate remoting techniques.
>
> It's there for certain tasks, however it's not supported in a lot of
>   ways.

**Applies to**

> **.NET Core**
>
> - 3.0 2.2 2.1 2.0
>
> **.NET Framework**
>
> - 4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0 1.1
>
> **.NET Standard**
>
> - 2.1 2.0

So what happens if you use something that is not supported?

It's either not there, or you get a big nasty evident `throw new NotSupportedException` or `PlatformNotSupportedException` depending on the when where and whys

**Further reading**

- https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md#is-appdomain-part-of-net-standard
- https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/faq.md#why-do-you-include-apis-that-dont-work-everywhere